# Filtering ng-repeat to value of table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I am currently trying to filter a ng-repeat to only show indexes that have the same album name as their parent albums. I can't get anything to filter, it is just displaying every single song instead. My code ...

Album/Song array.

```
$scope.albums = [
    {
        id: 'one',
        title: ' - Gregs Shoes',
        img: 'imgs/cover1.png',
        songs : [
            {
                id: 'one',
                title: 'Rain',
                url: 'http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/rain.mp3',
                album: ' - Gregs Shoes'
            },
            {
                id: 'two',
                title: 'Angry cow sound?',
                url: 'http://www.freshly-ground.com/data/audio/binaural/Mak.mp3',
                album: ' - Gregs Shoes'
            },
            {
                id: 'three',
                title: 'Things that open, close and roll',
                url: 'http://www.freshly-ground.com/data/audio/binaural/Things%20that%20open,%20close%20and%20roll.mp3',
                album: ' - Gregs Shoes'
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        id: 'two',
        title: ' - Hankey Pankey',
        img: 'imgs/cover2.jpg',
        songs : [
            {
                id: 'one',
                title: 'Walking',
                url: 'http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/walking.mp3',
                album: ' - Hankey Pankey'
            },
            {
                id: 'two',
                title: 'Barrlping with Carl (featureblend.com)',
                url: 'http://www.freshly-ground.com/misc/music/carl-3-barlp.mp3',
                album: ' - Hankey Pankey'
            }
        ]
    },

     {
        id: 'three',
        title: ' - Gross Misc.',
        img: 'imgs/cover3.jpg',
        songs : [
            {
                id: 'one',
                title: 'inDreworkdd.jpeg',
                url: 'todo',
                album: ' - Gross Misc.'
            },
            {
                id: 'two',
                title: 'Protsin',
                url: 'todo',
                album: ' - Gross Misc.'
            },
            {
                id: 'three',
                title: 'Little Baggies',
                url: 'todo',
                album: ' - Gross Misc.'
            },
            {
                id: 'four',
                title: 'Coriolis',
                url: 'todo',
                album: ' - Gross Misc.'
            },
            {
                id: 'five',
                title: 'Really Poppin',
                url: 'todo',
                album: ' - Gross Misc.'
            },
            {
                id: 'six',
                title: 'Cowhisper',
                url: 'todo',
                album: ' - Gross Misc.'
            }
        ]
    },
];
```

Opening a album. (setting currentAlbum variable)

```
<li ng-repeat="album in albums">
            <div style="background: url({{album.img}}); background-size: contain;" class="aAlbum">
                <button play-all="album" my-playlist="playlist" style="text-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #000;">&#9658;</button>
                <a href="#album" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" ng-click="selectedAlbum=album.title">go</a>
            </div>
        </li>
```

and finally trying to filter songs by album name with selectedAlbum.

```
<div my-directive>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="album in albums">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="song in album.songs | filter: selectedAlbum">
                    <p>{{song.title}}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <a href="#">Back</a>
</div>
```

And the directive that should allow me to use selectedAlbum.

```
animateApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        selectedAlbum: 0
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not list all the songs per album and simply filter by the album instead of applying `filter` inside the nested `ng-repeat`? Here's a bare bones implementation I've carved up for you (http://plnkr.co/edit/Ncdkb7LWroEhufXBerev?p=preview). As an aside, you probably shouldn't filter by the selected album name—that's what IDs are for.

Comment: Now how could I make those functions and that variable cross module?

Comment: sorry i don't understand why you have to filter when the data is already modeled hierarchically...

Comment: @WolfNinja2, for demonstration purposes, I've thrown everything into an `ng-controller`, but there's nothing stopping you from refactoring that into a `directive` or `component`, like so - http://plnkr.co/edit/OK8AyQ0Rrl7AmvVi9VSy?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

To display filtered song titles from a specific album,

```
 <li ng-repeat="song in album.songs | filter: {album: ' - Specific Album Name'}">
```

Comment: Okay, how can I go about using the selectedAlbum variable as the ' - Specific Album Name'?

Comment: @WolfNinja2 What are you trying to achieve with the directive? The selectedAlbum variable has to be a string.

Comment: It gets set though by ng-click later? I also set it to a string and the solution that @j.wittwer gave still doesn't work.

Comment: @WolfNinja2 You can try using `data-ng-init =' selectedAlbum = "" '` to initialise the variable within the scope that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering, you could let `ng-if` control which albums get rendered:

```
<li ng-repeat="album in albums" ng-if="album.title === selectedAlbum">
```

Comment: That is super helpful but doing so renders nothing, I must not be setting selectedAlbum properly?

Comment: It could be that your ng-click sets the selectedAlbum in a child scope.  Try setting an object property like selected.albumTitle instead.